# Hibernate not synchronized with database

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate(3.5.6-Final) for my web project. The problem is, when I change a data with one of the users I can't see the change with the other user. I guess the second one still works from cache. I am fetching the data with this method(Newsletter class is my Entity class):

```
public static List<Newsletter> getNewsletters() {
        List<Newsletter> newsletter = new ArrayList<Newsletter>();
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateConfiguration.getSession();
            session.clear();
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Newsletter.class);
            newsletter = criteria.list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return newsletter;
    }
```

And I am saving the data with the following method:

```
public static void save(Object o) throws Exception{
        Session session = HibernateConfiguration.getSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(o);
        transaction.commit();
        session.evict(o);
        session.close();
    }
```

As I understand there isn't a way to turn off the cache(unless using stateless session).

Does anyone has any idea what should I modify to keep the datas of the users in sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid evicting your object out of session
documentation( http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict(java.lang.Object) )

says that this will prevent synchronizing changes in database.

And you really ought to use filter  and avoid to manage session in your application code